# Instance argument: cannot convert from IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> to ParallelQuery<SalesTaxRate>

Tags: c#, linq

cannot select specific column in Linq got this error

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<LINQ.SalesTaxRate>'

```
private void Button_Click_7(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (LinqContainer context = new LinqContainer())
    {
        List<SalesTaxRate> salesTaxRateList = (from c in context.SalesTaxRates
                                               select new {c.TaxRate })
                                                     .ToList<SalesTaxRate>();
        grid.ItemsSource = salesTaxRateList;

    }
}
```

Comment: You really should elaborate what is happening, maybe show the code that is causing this error.

Comment: here is the code whenever i select new.I got the error message ay .ToList

Comment: Thanks, I can't answer this but that should help someone else see whats going on :)

Comment: Your code shouldn't cause the error you're describing, since there is no `ParallelQuery` there.

Comment: What exactly is SalesTaxRates? Is it for example a Table<T> or a function which is attempting to use Parallel LINQ? Does my concise version without the new {} throw the same error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot cast the anonymous type to a SalesTaxRate object

```
new { c.TaxRate }
```

This does not create a SalesTaxRate object and the ParallelQuery<AnonymousType> cannot be converted it to List<SalesTaxRate>

Try

```
new SalesTaxRate(c.TaxRate)
```

or

```
new SalesTaxRate { TaxRate = c.TaxRate }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the `select new {c.TaxRate}` part of the following line

```
        List<SalesTaxRate> salesTaxRateList = (from c in context.SalesTaxRates
                                                   select new {c.TaxRate })
                                                         .ToList<SalesTaxRate>();
```

For each `SalesTaxRate` object in `context.SalesTaxRates`, this creates an object of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).  This anonymous type has a single property `TaxRate`, whose type is the type of the `TaxRate` property.  You are getting a compiler error because the C# compiler can't figure out how to convert instances of this anonymous type to `SalesTaxRate`.

You haven't shown how `SalesTaxRates` is defined.  It looks to me like it is an Entity Framework EntitySet - is it?  If so, names of entity sets are often the plural of the name of the entity.  So, I would expect `SalesTaxRates` to be a collection of `SalesTaxRate` objects.  If this is the case, the code you want is

```
        List<SalesTaxRate> salesTaxRateList = context.SalesTaxRates.ToList();
```

However, if you really do want a list of the values of the `TaxRate` properties of your `SalesTaxRate` objects, which is what it seems your code is trying to achieve, then simply get rid of the anonymous type:

```
        List<SalesTaxRate> salesTaxRateList = (from c in context.SalesTaxRates
                                                   select c.TaxRate)
                                                         .ToList();
```

(Unless I've misunderstood, this would mean that your `SalesTaxRate` objects in `context.SalesTaxRates` have a property named `TaxRate`, also of type `SalesTaxRate`.  I don't have the definition of your `SalesTaxRate` type so I can't say whether or not this is true.)

Comment: But this doesn't explain the `ParallelQuery` part of the error message, right?

Comment: @svick: no, it doesn't.  There are a lot of things about this question that are unclear and that is one of them.